# Java timer not working, runs endlessly

Tags: java, timer, timertask

- **I'm running the program for 5 minutes. It shows no errors but when it runs the time remaining stays the same**
- I am working on a time-driven single server or multiple server queue system with
  following specifications:
- Calls arrive at an average rate of 20 calls per minute.
- When a call arrives (random callID), the call is placed in a queue.
- The service time for a call varies from 3 seconds to 16 seconds (use random number and computer clock time)
- Calls are served at a maximum of 7 seconds at once, if a call required service time more
  than 7 seconds, for the remaining service time the call is placed back on the queue
  (enqueue) again

Here's my coding:

```
package callcenter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CallCenter extends TimerTask {

ArrayList<Caller> Server1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Caller> Server2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Caller> Queue = new ArrayList<>();
Random rand = new Random();

int count = 7,
count1 = 7,
time = rand.nextInt(301) + 300;

public static int firstattempt = 0;
public static int queued1 = 0;
public static int queued2 = 0;
public static int attempt = 0;
public static int callcounter = 0;
public static int Processed = 0;

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    TimerTask task = new CallCenter();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,1000);
}

@Override
public void run() {


    if ((Server1.isEmpty() == false) || (Server2.isEmpty() == false)){
        ReceiveCall();
        callcounter++;

        if (count > 0){

            if(Server1.get(0).getServiceTime() > 1){

                Server1.get(0).setServiceTime();
                count--;

            }

            else{

                count = 7;
                attempt = Server1.get(0).getAttempt();
                Server1.remove(0);
                if(attempt == 1){
                    firstattempt++;
                }
                else if(attempt == 2){
                    queued1++;
                }
                else if(attempt == 3){
                    queued2++;
                }

                if(Queue.size() > 0){
                    Server1.add(Queue.get(0));
                    Queue.remove(0);
                    Processed++;
                }

            }

        }

        else{

            Server1.get(0).setAttempt();
            Queue.add(Server1.get(0));
            Server1.remove(0);
            if(Queue.size() > 0){

                Server1.add(Queue.get(0));
                Queue.remove(0);
                Processed++;
            }
            count = 7;

        }

        if (count1 > 0){

            if(Server2.get(0).getServiceTime() > 1){

                Server2.get(0).setServiceTime();
                count1--;

            }

            else{

                count1 = 7;
                attempt = Server2.get(0).getAttempt();
                Server2.remove(0);
                if(attempt == 1){
                    firstattempt++;
                }
                else if(attempt == 2){
                    queued1++;
                }
                else if(attempt == 3){
                    queued2++;
                }

                if(Queue.size() > 0){
                    Server2.add(Queue.get(0));
                    Queue.remove(0);
                    Processed++;
                }

            }

        }

        else{

            Server2.get(0).setAttempt();
            Queue.add(Server2.get(0));
            Server2.remove(0);
            if(Queue.size() > 0){
                Server2.add(Queue.get(0));
                Queue.remove(0);
                Processed++;
            }
            count1 = 7;

        }

    }

    else if (Queue.size() > 0) {

        if(Server1.isEmpty() == false) {

            Server2.add(Queue.get(0));
            Queue.remove(0);
            Processed++;
        }
        else{

            Server1.add(Queue.get(0));
            Queue.remove(0);
            Processed++;
        }
    }

    else {
        ReceiveCall();
        callcounter++;
    }

    Format();

}


public void ReceiveCall(){

    int SAssign;
    Caller c = new Caller();

    c.setCallerID();
    c.setRandomTime();
    c.setAttempt();


    SAssign = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;

    if (SAssign == 1){
        if(Server1.isEmpty() == false){
            Queue.add(c);
        }

        else {
            Server1.add(c);
            Processed++;
        }
    }

    else if(SAssign== 2){           
        if(Server2.isEmpty() == false){               
            Queue.add(c);             
        }

        else {              
            Server2.add(c);
            Processed++;
        }          
    }


}

public void CountDown(){

    if (this.time != 0) {
        --this.time;
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}


 public void Format (){

    int x = 0;
    String Service = null;
    String Time1= null;
    String Service2 = null;
    String Time2 = null;

    if (Server1.size() > 0){

        Service = Server1.get(0).toString();
        Time1 = Integer.toString(Server1.get(0).getServiceTime());

    }

    if (Server2.size() > 0){

        Service2 = Server2.get(0).toString();
        Time2 = Integer.toString(Server2.get(0).getServiceTime());

    }


    System.out.println("Time Remaining: " + time + " seconds");
    System.out.println("Server 1: \n" + Service + " | " + Time1);
    System.out.println("Server 2: \n" + Service2 + " | " + Time2);
    System.out.println("Queue: ");

    if (Queue.size() > 0){

        while(x < Queue.size()){

            System.out.println(Queue.get(x));
            x++;

        }
    }

    if (time == 0){
    System.out.println("Total number of calls processed are : "+ Processed);
    System.out.println("Average number of calls processed per minute is : "+ (double)(Processed/60.0));
    System.out.println("Average arrival rate per minute is : "+ (double)(callcounter/60.0));
    System.out.println("Number of calls processed in first attempt : "+ firstattempt);
    System.out.println("Number of calls had to be requeued once : "+ queued1);
    System.out.println("Number of calls had to be requeued twice : "+ queued2);
    }
}
}
```

Caller.java

```
package callcenter;
import java.util.Random;
public class Caller {
Random rand = new Random();

int CallerID;
int ServiceTime;
int Attempt = 0;
String Name;

public Caller() {
    this.CallerID = CallerID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    Name = Integer.toString(CallerID);
    return Name;
}
public void setCallerID() {
    this.CallerID = rand.nextInt(3000) + 2000;
}

public int getCallerID() {
    return CallerID;
}

public int getServiceTime() {
    return ServiceTime;
}

public void setRandomTime() {
    this.ServiceTime = rand.nextInt(14) + 3;
}

public void setServiceTime() {
    this.ServiceTime = ServiceTime - 1;
}

public void setAttempt() {
    this.Attempt++;
}

public int getAttempt() {
    return Attempt;
}

}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? And unrelated: please read about clean code. You are stuffing way too many things and nesting levels into your poor methods.

Comment: there are no set amount of iterations for Timer it just keeps going. Do you really want this thing to run for 5 min? you can model time yourself. start at 0, generate all the calls that are going to happen for that day and what time they come in.increment clock to time of first call. then you have to see what happens next  does the job finish, does another job arrive.... keep incrementing time till it gets to 300 seconds.